# Connect with PayPal - invalid_client Client Authentication failed with sandbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am implementing Connect With PayPal on my vuejs application following [this documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/connect-with-paypal/integrate/#), but I keep getting an invalid_client error when I try to get the access token.

I have created the sandbox REST app on my account and I've enabled "Connect With PayPal". I have also set my return url in the app settings. To build the button I used the [button builder](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/connect-with-paypal/reference/button-js-builder/) and specified my client id, return url and set auth end point as "sandbox". I have added the external script in my index.html and the paypal.use() method in my component.

So now I have the connect button on my interface and when I click on it I am redirected to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/connect/ which is normal. I can login with my two default sandbox accounts, then I am redirected to the return url that I specified in my app settings, with two url parameters : "code" and "scope" as described in the documentation.

However I am stuck at [this step](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/connect-with-paypal/integrate/#6-get-access-token) where I need to get an access token for the connected user.

I have tried to run [this curl request](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/connect-with-paypal/integrate/#sample-request) with my client id / secret and the code from the url but as I said before it doesn't work and I am getting this error everytime :

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Length: 77
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Wed, 08 Jul 2020 22:01:03 GMT
Paypal-Debug-Id: 8abaa5940b688
X-Paypal-Token-Service: IAAS

{
  "error":"invalid_client",
  "error_description":"Client Authentication failed"
}
```

I have checked my client id and secret multiple times and I can't understand why this is not working, does anyone have an idea ?

Comment: Show your actual full curl request -- including sandbox tokens/credentials since that isn't sensitive

Comment: @PrestonPHX why would you need that ? Here is the curl request : 

```curl -X POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
-H 'Authorization: Basic CLIENT_ID:CLIENT_SECRET' \
-d 'grant_type=authorization_code&code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE'```
I have tried the same thing with the default REST app in my account but got the same result

Comment: Impossible to advise on a client authentication failure error without seeing the actual request, and with only placeholder values in the request. We can't see what you may be doing wrong if you don't show us.

Comment: @PrestonPHX ok here is the request with the values ```curl -X POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
-H 'Authorization: Basic AdOdV_kjaq72iOk_eynngogJZoH8lJGMi7fmVUd0CmM8NV-xArVR2gGWU6mkykfAXPoon7Sq31A217qU:EOoCOJcrBO_JAi-i4sUK8ipBqvWfA8Lce-ThJzsyoQW0as-JBPgqmDUbJL8ozX3rbMd7bu1wAKl2dgYy' \
-d 'grant_type=authorization_code&code=C21AAEynkQgjBV0CkM0rIwbXR_RMA1Wo2fvjbA-aXw1V4taL6s_aycnGiZRCGioqmeR1o5NFjJzMHWtyYhHVMZK-R__Zva2OA'```
I am not testing this in my code at this point, I try to run the request on my terminal or on https://reqbin.com/curl

Comment: I just tried with my client id and secret encoded in base64 but I get this :
```{
    "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "Authorization Header must have client_id and secret"
}```

Comment: Simpler syntax than base encoding yourself, let curl do it: `curl -X POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token -u 'AdOdV_kjaq72iOk_eynngogJZoH8lJGMi7fmVUd0CmM8NV-xArVR2gGWU6mkykfAXPoon7Sq31A217qU:EOoCOJcrBO_JAi-i4sUK8ipBqvWfA8Lce-ThJzsyoQW0as-JBPgqmDUbJL8ozX3rbMd7bu1wAKl2dgYy' -d 'grant_type=authorization_code&code=C21AAEynkQgjBV0CkM0rIwbXR_RMA1Wo2fvjbA-aXw1V4taL6s_aycnGiZRCGioqmeR1o5NFjJzMHWtyYhHVMZK-R__Zva2OA'`

Comment: @PrestonPHX thank you, I tried this with a new auth code and it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for this type of error is to verify and validate everything is being sent correctly in the request, and properly encoded

curl's `-u` flag makes username:password header authentication easier

curl's `-v` flag will give visibility about the actual communication, to validate

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I usually don't use curl, I'll know it for next time!